# Insert Raw Text in MySQL db using Python 2.7

Tags: regex, python-2.7, mysql-python

I am trying to insert text, that I have parsed using the re module, into a mysql database. The problem is mysql is reading the quotes in the parsed text (i.e. 6" inch heels) and giving me an error message of incorrect syntax. When there are no quotes in the parsed text, the following code works:

```
import re
import MySQLdb as mysql 

f = open("All/text.txt", "rb")
string = f.read()

requirements = re.findall(r"text :(.*?)text", string, re.DOTALL)
requirements = requirements[0]
requirements = str(requirements)#Parse out the requirements in between the two text delimiters

print requirements

host = "localhost"
usernm = "root"
password = "Password"
database = "test"


dbConnection = mysql.connect(host=host, user=usernm, passwd=password, db=database, local_infile = True)
cursor = dbConnection.cursor()


sql = """INSERT INTO test (requirements) VALUES ("%s")"""%requirements#Write the parsed text being held in the requirements variable into the test table, requirements columns

cursor.execute(sql)


dbConnection.commit()
cursor.close()
```

The problem here is that if the text file that I am parsing has any quotes in it then it will fail because mySQL is reading the Quotes. I did some research and tried the following

```
import re
import MySQLdb as mysql 

f = open("All/text.txt", "rb")
string = f.read()

requirements = re.findall(r"text :(.*?)text", string, re.DOTALL)
requirements = requirements[0]
requirements = str(requirements)#Parse out the requirements in between the two text delimiters

print requirements

host = "localhost"
usernm = "root"
password = "Password"
database = "test"


dbConnection = mysql.connect(host=host, user=usernm, passwd=password, db=database, local_infile = True)
cursor = dbConnection.cursor()


sql = """INSERT INTO test (requirements) VALUES ("%s")"""#Write the parsed text being held in the requirements variable into the test table, requirements columns

cursor.execute(sql, (requirements))



dbConnection.commit()
cursor.close()
```

I moved the requirments inside the cursor.execute but unfortunately this gives me an error message:

cursor.execute(sql, (requirements))   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 187, in
execute
query = query % tuple([db.literal(item) for item in args]) **TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting**

I want to be able to eneter all the characters that are parsed from the text file and enter the raw text (hopefully easily escape the entire string)  into the mysql table.

I am new to python, completely lost and would really appreciate some help here. Thanks - Benipy

Comment: During string formatting? Is the formatted string somehow being interpolated after it goes into a variable? If that's the case you'd have to escape the double quotes (`""` or `\"`) before being used in the format statement.

Answer (score 0):

Replace
    cursor.execute(sql, (requirements))
on
    cursor.execute(sql, (requirements,))